# Installing openssl in php 5.3 docker container

Tags: php, docker, openssl

I have a php project with docker
The docker-compose file is as shown below

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  php:
    image: php:5.3-apache
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5030:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      # - /home/asish/Work/CodePoint/php/php.ini:/usr/local/lib/php.ini

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5001:3306"

    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - UPLOAD_LIMIT=300000000
```

I need to install openssl extension and activate it. I tried mapping a php.ini file with openssl extension enabled but it is not enabled in the server.

How to install and activate the openssl extension in this case

Comment: Hello, Did you ever figure it out?. I need the exact same thing?